# assembly LINK : fatal error L1093:object file not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86, masm

I want to write 16 bit 8086 assembly code in visual studio 2010
but gives me error:
code:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.data
 message BYTE "Hello, world!","$"
.code
_start:
mov ah,9
lea dx,message ; addr of buffer
int 21h
END _start
```

output gives me this error:

```
Link:  
Microsoft (R) Segmented Executable Linker  Version 5.60.339 Dec  5 1994
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1993.  All rights reserved.  
warning L4017: /ERRORREPORT : unrecognized option name; option ignored
LINK : fatal error L1093: Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe : 
object file not found
Build FAILED.
```

what should I to do?

Comment: why did you not use start: and end start from the answer to your other question?

Comment: I used start but forgot put it in question!

Comment: it is telling you the object file was not found.   did ml give you any errors?

Comment: all output is that I wrote above! I think ml has no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really not sure what the problem is.  I have never uses VS for Assembly.  There are great Assembly IDEs out there that are better than VS IMHO - RadASM, WinASM.
This code:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.data
 message BYTE "Hello, world!","$"
.code
_start:
mov ah,9
lea dx,message ; addr of buffer
int 21h
END _start
```

Assembles and links fine with this batch file:

```
@ECHO ON
del dosdisplay.exe
ML.EXE /DMASM /DDOS /Zm /c /nologo /I"d:\masm32\Include" "dosdisplay.asm"
link16.exe /NOLOGO "dosdisplay.obj" "",,,,,""
```

Assembler and Linker versions that I use:

`Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.15.8803`

`Microsoft (R) Segmented Executable Linker Version 5.60.339 Dec 5 1994`

What is link?  Isn't that the 32bit version?  or is the 16bit name the same?  Not sure, been using these 2 files/versions for many, many years for DOS apps.

Answer (score -1):

**This problem is arise:**

> 1.due to the long name of .asm file. Shorten your file name and get your desired results.
>
> > 2.due to wrong path when linking your file.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little?